# borrar datos de tablas y resetear ID identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd

Tengo dos comandos por separados que hacen la tarea, pero quiero ponerlos en uno solo.
Primero que borre los datos de la tabla y cuando termine que se resete el ID a 0

Comando sqlcmd para borrar:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLServidor -d database -q "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID IS NOT NULL"
```

Comando para resetear el ID a 0:

```
sqlcm -S SQLServidor -d database -Q "USE database DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName, RESEED, 0)" and exit
```

Quiero poner ambos querys en un solo archivo .bat

Saludos.

Comment: Y si lo pones en un sp y solo mandas a llamar a ese sp?

Comment: No te sirve hacer un `truncate table TablaABorrarTodo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes escribir todo el query, separando cada clausula por `;`:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLServidor -d database -q "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;USE database;DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName, RESEED, 0);"
```

De todas formas te hago unos comentarios:

- `WHERE ID IS NOT NULL` entiendo que es redundante, si `ID` es el `IDENTITY` no debería poder ser `NULL`
- Si el `IDENTITY` de la tabla ya comienza desde `1`, puedes lograr un efecto similar a los dos comandos, usando simplemente `TRUNCATE TableName`

Comment: voy a probar con TRUNCATE

Comment: use el sqlcmd con el truncate pero se queda abierta la ventana del sqlcmd, que le agrego para cuando se termine de ejecutar el query se cierre la ventana?

Comment: @Manny, en ves de usar `-q` usa `-Q` (mayúscula), eso ejecutará el query y finalizará la sesión